# Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have developed two method one for the form and the other to modify a reservation. A message and an error message appears: "Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present. Could you help me please
My controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reservations")
public class ReservationController {
@Autowired
ReservationService reservationService;
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Autowired
ClassroomService classroomService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/updatereservationForm", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView UdateReservationSalle(@RequestParam(value="id",   
required = true) Integer id, ModelMap model) {
Reservation reservation = reservationService.findById(id)   ;
model.addAttribute("reservation", reservation);
List <Classroom> classrooms = classroomService.getAll();
model.addAttribute("classrooms", classrooms);
List <User> users = userService.getAll();
model.addAttribute("users", users);
return new ModelAndView("reservation/updateResR", model);
}    

@RequestMapping("/updateReservation")
public ModelAndView updateResR(@RequestParam("id") Integer id,ModelMap 
model) {
Reservation reservation=reservationService.findById(id);
model.addAttribute("reservation",reservation);
return new ModelAndView("updateResR",model);
}

@RequestMapping("/updateReservationRInput")
public ModelAndView updateReservationRInput
(@RequestParam("id") Integer id,
@RequestParam(name="roomid",defaultValue="-1") Integer roomid,
@RequestParam("datebegin") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")  
Date  datebegin,@RequestParam("dateend") 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = 
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") Date dateend, 
Integer userid,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, ModelMap model)
Reservation reservation = reservationService.findById(id);
Classroom classroom = classroomService.findById(roomid);
User user = userService.findById(userid);
reservation.setClassroom(classroom);
reservation.setUser(user);
reservation.setDateBegin(datebegin);
reservation.setDateEnd(dateend);
return testReservation(roomid, datebegin, dateend,
redirectAttributes,reservation);
}
```

And my page JSP is:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="security" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Gestion des réservation</title>
 </head>
   <body>
 
 <form method=GET action="/reservations/updateReservationRInput">
  Salles : <select name="roomid">
    <option value=""></option>

     <c:forEach items="${classrooms}" var="classroom">
    <c:if test="${reservation.classroom.id==classroom.id}">
     <option value="${classroom.id}" selected="selected">${classroom.name}</option>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${reservation.classroom.id!=classroom.id}">
     <option value="${classroom.id}">${classroom.name}</option>
    </c:if>
   </c:forEach></select>
   
   Date Debut : <input type="datetime-local" name="datebegin"
   value=<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" 
   value="${reservation.datebegin}"/>> 
   
  
  DateFin : <input type="datetime-local" name="dateend"
   value=<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
   value="${reservation.dateend}"/>>
   
  
  user Id:   <input name="id" value="${reservation.id}" type="hidden" />
     <select name="userid">
    <option value=""></option>
      <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <c:if test="${reservation.user.id==user.id}">
     <option value="${user.id}" selected="selected">${user.name}&nbsp;${user.surname}</option>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${reservation.user.id!=user.id}">
     <option value="${user.id}">${user.name}&nbsp;${user.surname}</option>
    </c:if>
   </c:forEach>
  </select> 
  <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
 </form>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me :)

Comment: First off all, plz format your code, properly. This is unreadable. Second, try replacing `Integer` by `int` and add `, BindingResult result` as the last input parameter. This allows you to enter the method regardless and you can check the error more detailed by `result.getErrors()` or something similar. Can't recall the exact method name

Comment: I can't replasing Integer by int because in my Entity:' reservation.java i déclarat:

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")//reservId
    private Integer id;